# libLinear matlab impementation returns abnormal results

Tags: svm, matlab

Well hello,

this is my first question in CrossValidated. I hope I am in the right place.
I am trying to make libLinear work. I am using the interface of matlab but it does not functions normally. To be more specific I have a dataset with multiple labels and so I tries to solved it by constructing multiple binary problems. The problem I am facing has to do with the solution is not correspond to a binary problem sometimes?

I experimented with random toy samples with the following code:

```
S = 1;
C = 1;
e = 0.1;
B = 1;
parameters = sprintf('-s %d -c %1.5f -e %1.5f -B %1.3f', S, C, e, B);

N = 2000;
X1 = rand(N,10);
X2 = rand(N*1.2,10);
X = [X1; X2];
Xlabels = [ones(N,1); zeros(N*1.2,1)];
model = train(sparse(Xlabels), sparse(X), parameters);
```

A random output is

```
model = 

    Parameters: 1
      nr_class: 3
    nr_feature: 10
          bias: 1
         Label: [3x1 double]
             w: [3x11 double]
```

How come **w** has 3 lines? It's like its a three class problem! I checked the labels returned by the model and it adds one more like -2.1475e+09 besides the normal {0,1}! I am certainly missing something here and I cannot understand why. The problem does not occur always though. Sometimes it just returns the usual **w** with dimensions 1x11. 
Also I skipped the parameters argument (which is the default by the way anyway) and nothing changes.
For random 60 run the number of classes varied from 2 to 8 (all values included!).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Well I cannot answer my question yet! Anyway I found the answer if anyone is interested: dense labels and (maybe labels 1,-1 instead of 1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can finally answer my question.

It turns out that I accidentally made the labels vector also sparse (which is easy in Matlab) but I shouldn't have. So the solution is to use only the data matrix as sparse.

The funny thing is that when I introduced different labels than {0,1}, more specifically {-1,1} it also worked! Maybe it has to do with the implementation of the code.

Anyway if someone does the same mistake here is a solution.